# Validate first 3 rows of txt file (tsv) in Python

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, validation

I have been trying to build a validation rule for txt files that get uploaded to my environment. The files are tab separated and I need to validate the first 3 rows that are in a format such as:

```
## This Text Here 
## This Text Here
## This Text Here
```

I need to build a pass fail validation. I have tried doing this with the inbuilt csv function in python with no luck so far.
Would appreciate any advice on the best route to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
### it depends on how you open the file but...
# open using with..
with open("test.tsv") as inData:
    # split lines on tabs...
    allLines = [l.split("\t") for l in inData]
    # get the lines in question:
    testLines = [l[0] for l in allLines[:3]]
    # then you could use assert
    for l in testLines:
        assert(l.startswith("##"))
        # and whatever other validation you need for the string
    ### you could ad try/except
    try:
        for l in testLines:
            assert(l.startswith("##"))
    except AssertionError as e:
        print(e, "please use a validated file!")
```

Further reading:https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_exceptions.htm

Comment: Great this is exactly what I needed. Didn't know about "Assert".

Comment: Np - it's a very useful and sometimes under-appreciate function. If you wouldn't mind accepting the answer that would be mint!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should give a try pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

file_name = # your file name
csv = pd.read_csv(file_name, sep='\t')

# do your stuff
```

Documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html